# Ubuntu 16.04 not detecting when headphones are plugged

Tags: 16.04, headphones, pavucontrol

My Ubuntu doesn't recognize when the headphones are plugged in. If I go to pavucontrol and switch the output to "Headphones(unplugged)" it works perfectly whoever it doesn't detect them automatically.

How can this be fixed?

Edit: aplay -l returns this

me@minime:~$ sudo aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]

Subdevices: 0/1

Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]

Subdevices: 1/1

Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: seems duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/914608/ubuntu-16-04-headphones-are-not-working/931817