# Ubuntu 16.04 headphones are not working

Tags: 16.04, sound, headphones, audio-jack

Reminder: I have reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 from scratch but it didn't help, the problem still exists.

---

I am using Windows 10 with Ubuntu as dual boot. The problem is I can not make headphones work. They work just fine on Win 10. ***Apparently my headphone jack is not compatible with Ubuntu. How can I make Ubuntu see my headphone jack ?***

[Headphone jack not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working)

**I have tried every method in above link.**

Headphones: Apple

When I plug in my headphones they don't even appear under:
[System Settings > Sound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7s5x.png)

Built-in Speakers are working fine. If extra information is needed, let me know.

---

```
$ lspci | grep Audio
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller 
(rev 0a)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset 
High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
```

---

AlsaInfo

- Headphones are connected -> [AlsaInfo](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=13fdd0b3d299514a41d1f6fa34473abd1c3f302f)

---

Alsa-base.conf

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m6-amic
```

Comment: Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132440/headphone-jack-not-working) question please. Linux is great but there are fewer out of the box options. Anyway you can do almost anything just some extra work may be needed.

Comment: What type of machine are you on? What do you see when you open the System Settings > Sound?  Linux is a great platform for many reasons.  However, to get help for an issue on your system you need to provide more information.  Here's some tips for asking good questions to get good answers: https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Xaqron I have tried all of the methods stated in that link. I am using Windows 10 with dual boot Ubuntu. The headphones are apple and When I open System Settings > Sound, I can not see my headphones, only the built -in speakers. Again like I said, I have tried every solution in the above link.

Comment: Would you please provide [AlsaInfo](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo).

Comment: I have edited the question to include AlsaInfo @Xaqron

Comment: Try this `$ alsactl restore` in terminal.

Comment: I have tried everything in the link that I have provided, including `alsactl restore` @Xaqron.
Why is it so complicated ?

Comment: I couldn't get my headphones to work at all on 16.04.3 ASUS S200E laptop.
I've resorted to an external USB combined audio/mic jack adaptor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After searching for a solution for 2 months, I was able to solve my own problem. The problem also exists in Linux Mint, hence it's likely this is an issue which exists in Debian.

This post has useful information about the issue:

[[SOLVED]Front panel headphones not working with onboard Intel HD Audio](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=177547)

At some point it mentions a package `hda-jack-retask`. I have searched for it a little and found out that it's under `alsa-tools-gui`. Run it with,

```
sudo hdajackretask
```

In this GUI, I have overridden my front jack to headphones and installed boot override.

Now I have crystal clear sounds from my headphones and also it can detect whether they are plugged in or not! It mutes the speakers when they are plugged in.

---

This may not be a common issue. Other solutions I found on the internet just did not work.

Comment: Thanks so much, worked for me on 16.04 months ago, now that I upgraded to 18.04, the same solution worked.

Comment: Worked for me on ubuntu 20

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to get it working with above solution. Below one worked. 
Open terminal, install and open pavucontrol

```
$ sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
$ pavucontrol
```

This will open a 'volume control' window. In 'output device' section scroll down to 'Build-in Audio Analog Sterio'. Here change the port to "Headphones(unplugged)"

Comment: This one works fine on Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks..:-)

Answer (score 1):

My answer was the same as BcK's answer, except I had to override "headphone" to the "line out" port, see the image below. Everything works perfectly now, thanks Bck!

[image]

Comment: Thanks! My answer was similar except some fields (Location, Channel etc.) were different as I had to choose `Line out (Back)`.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution that isn't really a solution...

When I shutdown Windows 10 with the headphones plugged in, the headphones won't work in Ubuntu. When I shutdown Windows 10 without headphones the headphones will work in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I had a problem with sound back on Ubuntu 14.  My notes are cryptic but they mention a volume level of about 2%.  Perhaps a package such as pacmd could be useful?  Further in my old notes is a command sudo pacmd set-sink-volume 32600.  There is also a comment to be sure muted:no (don't know if that is also part of the pacmd stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try to mute and unmute via function panel (my ntb <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>f10</kbd>). After that my sound settings sync and my headphone started works.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link for solving HFP issues. I followed below procedure and then changed profile to HSP/HFP, codec CSVD and my true wireless earbuds microphone started to work.

https://atish3604.medium.com/solved-bluetooth-headset-mic-not-working-detected-in-ubuntu-20-04-86a5236444d0